# Using a single handler function to set the state of inputs in a form in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React and I can't find an easy way to create a single handler function to set the state of two inputs in a form. This is what I have so far:

```
<form onSubmit="onSave">
  <input type="text" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.setValue('name')}>
  <input type="text" value={this.state.bio onChange={this.setValue('bio')}>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      name: '',
      bio: '',
    }
  },
  setValue: function(key) {
    const self = this;
    return function(e) {
      var o = {};
      o[key] = e.target.value;
      self.setState(o);
    }
  },
  onSave() {
    console.log(this.state);
  }
});
```

The issue that I have is that only one input is updated. Also I'm aware of the form components out there, but I really want to know if something like this is possible, because my use case is very simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question, you could give your inputs a name and then do `setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})`.

Answer (score 1):

Use https://github.com/gcanti/tcomb-form react node-module. It has nice features and you can customize.

Or if you don't want to use any node module

```
setValue: function(key) {
 const self = this;
 return function(e) {
   var o = Object.defineProperty(self.state, key, {value: e.target.value});
   self.setState(o);
 }
},
```